# Smoothen a curve while keeping the area

Tags: algorithm, filtering, smoothing

I'm solving the 1D heat diffusion equation on a rather coarse grid. Now I'd like to add an additional discrete grid-point $x_0$ at some time( see the appended snapshot). [image: example temperature distribution.]

Is there a simple method to redistribute $u(x)$ to get a smooth curve while maintaining the integral temperature?

Comment: This seems like a nontrivial problem. A simple approach (which could work): smooth & shift/scale (= add offset / multiply with factor; to balance the integral). Shifting is a rather simple 1d-optimization problem.

Comment: Yes that offset method I'm currently using. I thought there could be a more elegant way.